# Checking & restoring non-renewing subscription via receipt allowed?

Tags: xcode

According to Apple's documentation, the receipt will always contain information about the users purchase of non-renewing subscriptions.
Is it an accepted implementation to manage the subscription period by using the purchased date in the receipt and also restore across device with SKReceiptRefresh? (Basically in the same way like auto-renewing subscriptions can be implemented by using the receipt information.)

In the past, there was a time when non-renewing subscriptions were not available in the receipt and the recommended way was to use either a Server or iCloud for across device restore.

However, if non-renewing subscriptions are now always in the receipt (and why wouldn't they be included??) it would be no problem to implement non-renewing subscriptions without a server component, on device only.

Are there any recent experiences about how app store review handles this? I want to avoid the situation were my implementation is accepted and then rejected some updates later, when it will be unclear how to migrate away from the implemented solution.
In the comments to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25208205/3195597 there is contradicting information about the App Store policy, but the comments are also a few years old.

Answer (score 2):

After earning the „Tumbleweed“ badge (asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week) for my question, I also get to answer it myself :-)

So my app got accepted without problems and I already published a further update, which was also accepted ... fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm in the same boat as you and your answer helped me decide on non-renewing subscriptions

Comment: Thanks for your update. It’s weird that your Nov 2018’s answer is one of the most recent post about non-renew subscription